# Is there any difference between the Job data returned from Databricks Jobs API 2.1 vs 2.0?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api, databricks-workflows

The main difference I see is that 2.1 **requires** paging results with a max page size of 25, while 2.0 does not support paging and will get you all of the results in one call.
Is there any difference in the structure or content of the "Job" objects returned from the Jobs Get and List apis, e.g. /api/2.0/jobs/list?
It is difficult for me to tell because I can't find the 2.0 specification, and the documentation just gives examples.

- [2.1 Open API specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_extras/api-refs/jobs-2.1-azure.yaml)
- [2.1 documentation (at time of post
  is the 'latest', but you can't specifically reference via the version 2.1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs)
- [2.0
  documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs)

Answer (score 1):

- The response returned from the `GET` methods of Jobs API 2.1 and 2.0 are different for each of the endpoints. The following is a sample response returned from each of the endpoints.

**jobs/list**:

When using jobs 2.0:

[image]

When using jobs 2.1:

[image]

- The difference here is that the cluster details and notebooks paths are missing in Jobs 2.1.

**jobs/get**:

- Using jobs 2.0:
  [image]
- Using jobs 2.1

[image]

- Information about tasks are present in Jobs API 2.1 but not in 2.0.

**jobs/runs/get**:

- There are not many notable differences using this endpoint.

**jobs/runs/get-output**:

- The response has been returned by the endpoint when using Jobs 2.0 API. But when using Jobs 2.1, it returned the following error:

[image]

So, the main difference for the `GET` methods is noticeable for `jobs/list` endpoint. The cluster details and the notebook details are absent in jobs 2.1 endpoint. Therefore, choose the API as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming you did not change the job between GET calls.  It looks like 2.1 returns format=MULTI_TASK even though it is a single task job, and when you retrieve the same job via 2.0 api, format=SINGLE_TASK.  I ran some tests with 2.0 retrieving jobs with multiple tasks, and it returned format=MULTI_TASK but the response is missing many details of the tasks and has no cluster details.  So, if you have multi-task jobs you should definitely use 2.1 api. Can you confirm, and do you agree?

Comment: I have used a single task job for all the cases above. Yes, Jobs 2.1 has returned format=MULTI_TASK even for SINGLE_TASK job for some reason. But the actual response content is same for both Jobs [2.0](https://i.imgur.com/f8brwro.png) and [2.1](https://i.imgur.com/zBTAqrs.png) in case of MULTI_TASK job. Considering all the additional functionality of Jobs 2.1 API as specified by @AlexOtt, I think it is a better choice for MULTI_TASK jobs.

Answer (score 1):

There are few significant changes between 2.0 & 2.1 APIs:

- Biggest change is support for jobs with multiple tasks:

  - now instead of single task in the top-level object you need to specify them in the `tasks` array
  - you can specify dependencies between tasks
  - you can reuse the [same job cluster between multiple tasks](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/02/04/saving-time-and-costs-with-cluster-reuse-in-databricks-jobs.html) - it will give your faster tasks startup
  - there are more supported task types in 2.1: dbt, sql, ...
- Similarly, things like, get run output are supporting multiple tasks, but for example, you can't get output for the top-level job run, but need to get it for individual tasks
- the `list` operation is now supporting paginated output that allows to overcome a previous limit of 3000 jobs per workspace. It also now supports listing of jobs by name
- there is a new API call for [repairing/re-runnign the failed tasks without the whole job](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/05/06/save-time-and-money-on-data-and-ml-workflows-with-repair-and-rerun.html).

Comment: This is very helpful. Are the differences between the Jobs API 2.0 and 2.1 documented somewhere.  I'm just wondering if I am missing it.

Comment: I don't remember really a published document that describes the exact differences.  I simply know them because of heavy use of it